# Save check marks in table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Hi I am new to xcode and I have been looking for an answer to my problem. I have a table view and I have check marks set up like a task list. I would like to know how I can save the check marks in my tasklist when I move from view to  view. Right now when I go to another view in my app the are gone when I come back to the table view controller. I don't have core data set up and I am not using a playlist. The code is simple here:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{  
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
}
```

Check to see if there is some simple code that would make this save when I come back to the table view.

Comment: You should format your code better in your next post. Thanks at vikingosegundo for fixing the code format.

Comment: You can add one field like selected in table and if the value is checked then update it with yes or 1 whatever value you want. And when you come back to tableview just in viewWillAppear get data from database and in cellforRowAtIndexPath just check if the value is selected then mark them as checked else uncheck. You can do it by creating your custom cell also.

Comment: I have core data working and it is pulling my data in from an array. I have a field called checkMark in core data set up as a string. I am wanting to use it to hold my checkmark if it's true. But now I am not sure how to connect the data from the cell to core data and back once the view loads. Again thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to preserve the state of checkmarks between app relaunches, the best solution seems to use Core Data.. While it may at first seem a bit overkill for what you're trying to do it will definitely pay off when your app gets more advanced. You'll already have a solid data management system on which you can build further.
In this case you'll probably want to create an entity representing a task, in the simplest case you'll only need two properties: an `NSString` name and an `BOOL` isCompleted.
Of course, all of this is possible using simple XML but it would be more future proof to use Core Data from the very beginning.

You can find more about Core Data here.
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html

Comment: Ok cool I didn't want to go that far but I guess I will have to. It is a lot over my head starting from scratch. I have been through a few tutorials with text boxes but I haven't found any with just adding a check mark. Thanks!!

Comment: Do you know if there is a tutorial with core data and check marks?

Comment: http://iosprogrammer.blogspot.be/2011/05/using-core-data-to-create-simple-to-do.html 
This tutorial should get you on the right track, however it doesn't offer that much explanation.. So it might be better to first follow http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started to get a basic understanding of how Core Data works before starting to build your application. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for this. Looks great.I have been able to get the core data going through a couple of tutorials but I can't seem to find one that show how to do check marks. Also whats weird is the check marks once I scroll up disappear. I made a static table works fine. I think it has something to do with the autorelease. Since I am doing this in arc I can't use it. Again thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem! Since you're using ARC, the compiler should take care of all memory management. So not being able to call `autorelease` shouldn't cause any additional problems.
However, you may want to open a new question showing what you got so far and what does and doesn't work. For basic checkmarks, you should look into setting the accessory type of a cell to `UITableViewCellAcessoryCheckmark`. You could maybe show some code so we can help you to get everything to behave perfectly.

Comment: Ok cool I got the check marks so they don't disappear any longer I was working today on NSUserDefaults and I was able to get text to be saved I was checking to see if this would work on check marks?

Comment: I think I understand NSUerDefaults better then core data and I just need the check marks on on this project. I can get text to be saved when I come back but I can't seem to get or know how to get the checkmarks to be saved. The question is should I post the code for the NSUserDefaults code here or start a new question. Don't want to get flagged for asking the same question.

Answer (score 0):

I have taken custom checkbox and in cellForRowAtIndexPath written:

```
       static NSString *CustomCellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";

       ReportAttendedBy *cell = (ReportAttendedBy *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CustomCellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nib;
            nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ReportAttendedBy" owner:self options:nil];
            for(id oneObject in nib)
                if([oneObject isKindOfClass:[ReportAttendedBy class]])
                    cell = (ReportAttendedBy *)oneObject;
        }

        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
        cell.textLabel.font= [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Rounded MT Bold" size:15.0];
        cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

        ReportCreateOrView *repVw= [arrAttendedBy objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.txtCustName.text = repVw.strCustomer;
        cell.txtCustName.tag = indexPath.row + 100;
        cell.txtCustName.delegate = self;
        [cell.txtCustName addTarget:self action:@selector(goAway:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];

        [cell.btnCheckBox addTarget:self action:@selector(checkboxClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        cell.btnCheckBox.tag = indexPath.row + 5000;

        NSLog(@"repVw.strSelected=== %@",repVw.strSelected);

        if([repVw.strSelected isEqualToString:@"1"])
        {
            [cell.btnCheckBox.currentBackgroundImage isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ckeckbox_checked.png"]];

          //  cell.txtCustName.userInteractionEnabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            [cell.btnCheckBox.currentBackgroundImage isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ckeckbox_unchecked.png"]];
            //cell.txtCustName.userInteractionEnabled = false;
        }

        return cell;
```

and i am maintaining checkbox value with 1 and zero in checkboxClicked method and as well as changing image of button

```
    -(IBAction)checkboxClicked:(id)sender
    {
        NSLog(@"tag=== %d",[sender tag] - 5000);

        int index= [sender tag] - 5000;
        UIButton *btn= (UIButton *)sender;

        ReportCreateOrView *repObj= [arrAttendedBy objectAtIndex:index];

        if([btn.currentBackgroundImage isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_unchecked.png"]])
        {
            [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"checkbox_checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            selCustId = [repObj.strCustId intValue];
            val = 1;
            [self updateAttendedBy]; //in this method i've written query to update value in table

        }
        else if([btn.currentBackgroundImage isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_checked.png"]])
        {
            [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"checkbox_unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            selCustId = [repObj.strCustId intValue];
            val= 0;
            [self updateAttendedBy];
        }
   }
```

And don't forget to write method to getvalues in viewWillAppear. :)

Comment: This looks great but I haven't worked with loading nib files before I have just used the storyboard to create what I have done. Sorry would I have to create a nib file named ReportAttendedBy with a table view?

Comment: Yes. you have to make class which of type UITableViewCell and and .xib file also which refer to this class.